# best practice/idiom in random number generator usage in libraries

Tags: c++, c++11, prng

Suppose I am writing a library that uses C++11's prng features. Should each function/object/file in the library initialize its own random number generator? I was going to go with initializing one static std::mt19937 in the namespace and using only that one after that, but the code would be less modular. Is this recommended?

Comment: you could use a singleton. That way you preserve modularity and use just one generator. Don't know how that will behave in practice though. Just a thought.

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  As an example, if your application required that you could provide a seed from a previous run and get the same result then it would seem a single source is appropriate.  Without a specific problem to solve any of your options could be appropriate.

Comment: Depending on the implementation, a prng like mt19937 can be larger than you think. The 32bit MS version from dinkum is over 5K. That may not seem like much, but it adds up when you have 50,000 objects, each of which is touting around one if you go the prng-per-member-route. (the example given is approx 244 **MB** just in prngs).

Comment: What I'm trying to do is general scientific computing. Working with mesh data, sometimes simulation, sometimes randomized ad hoc methods, and so on. I should probably take a look at how existing scientific computing libraries do it.

Comment: I think an alternative could be using a cheaper prng for problems that don't require as much stability

Comment: Thinking of the PRNG as a kind-of service, you wouldn't want to hard-code it into your library. Thinking about it as an implementation detail that is at most indirectly noticeable to the user of your library, you wouldn't want to expose it to the public. These two approaches are to some extent contradicting. Maybe if you could explain a bit what you are doing with the PRNG and what the library is doing, then you could get better suggestions how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not thread-safe, so if you're going to be spawning multiple threads, make more instances of the MT19937 prng.  Otherwise, it's totally up to you.  Any answer here beyond that is going to be primarily opinion-based.

If you're not memory-constrained, why try to optimize something so trivial as the number of instances of your prng out of the application?  Simple answer: do what makes your program easiest to write, debug, and manage.

A possible solution would be holding a reference  to the MT19937 in each object and controlling access to it through a locking construct to make it thread-safe.

Comment: Makes sense. How expensive is initializing the MT19937 instance?

Comment: That's going to be implementation-specific.  Honestly I don't know how large the version included with, say, visual studio is.  I'd have to profile it.  Making a naive guess, since MT19937 is 19937 bits of state, I'd say it's probably going to take at least 2.5KB of memory, simply to hold its state (19937 / 8 = 2492.125)